# What softly emotional connotation does a glistening ashtray give?

Tags: meaning, interpretation

I found the following definition of 'glisten' which is supposed to distinguish it from other similar verbs, such as glint, glitter, glimmer etc.:

"Something that "glistens" is generally particular - made up of or concerning particles. Sweat glistens, as does dew and tears. Eyes only glisten when they're emotional, and items only glisten when it's rained recently. As such, 'glisten' has more softly emotional connotations - it can even put a softly emotional edge on sweat, which is gross. It can be argued that sexualizing sweat with "glisten" is an exception."

If an item such as an ashtray glistens after it has rained, what sort of "softly emotional connotation" does it give the reader? And the same goes for sweat (please elaborate in terms of the explanation of glisten given above).

Lastly, how can you sexualize sweat with 'glisten'?

Answer (score -1):

Note that all the examples you have found using "glisten" are *liquids* - sweat, dew, tears.

Lexico (Oxford) dictionary's definition of 'glisten' is:

> (of something wet or greasy) shine with a sparkling light.

Cambridge says:

> to shine by reflecting light from a wet or smooth surface.

Although the second definition allows for smooth surfaces, not just wet ones, evidently *glisten* is more appropriate for surfaces that get their sheen from moisture or grease. For solid objects like glass that refract light, it might be more appropriate to use a word like *glint*.

Solid objects do reflect light differently to water. Water has moving molecules the light may appear to flicker by itself, whereas solid objects that reflect or refract light don't move, so any flickering is due to movement of the light source or other atmospheric conditions.

The reason 'glistens' might be used in some sexualised contexts is because mild perspiration is often associated with heightened sexual arousal, and sweat is supposed to contain pheromones. If a body was described as "glistening" it would be assumed that the person was perspiring, and in context that could sexualise the description.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to ask if you disagree with the definition I inserted in my original post to the extent that glisten cannot be used with items? Additionally, could you please explain the following extracted sentence: "it can even put a softly emotional edge on sweat" (so not the sexual aspect).

Comment: "Orbed is the moon and bright/And the stars they glisten, glisten" "The mammoth coronation portrait of Charles X (1757–1836) is 105 by 72 inches and glistens with power..." "The sunlight glistened off his hair..." "...in the lane, snow is glistening" "...where treetops glisten.." Just because glisten is often used to mean something sparkles as if it was wet or is lustrous doesn't mean it can't be used with solid objects. A glint is something else entirely, as is glittering. "The gem glistened in the light" is perfectly valid.

Comment: Surely you can imagine sexuality having an emotional context?

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways I would argue that moisture is what makes hair glisten. Did you notice that I included a dictionary definition? It includes "greasy" as well as moist.

Comment: @ManolisGustavsson From the dictionary definitions I quoted it seems *more common* to use 'glisten' with moisture. Evidently some disagree with me, but I don't think you can argue with the dictionary. Interestingly, someone asked a question the other day about the difference between "blinking" and "twinkling". Some might use them interchangeably, but there are clearly defined differences. I would think it is better to use a word you know to be correct than have someone pull you up for it because the dictionary says otherwise.

Comment: So stars are greasy? When a poet talks of the sun glistening off his lover's hair, they aren't remarking on how long it's been since they washed it. See [Jewels glistening in the sun](https://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/1280545/) (Pictures of completely dry and solid hummingbirds). Yes, glistening is often associated with moisture, but "solid" objects can have sub-surface scattering too and not just reflections that "glint". A glisten is a gentle sparkle, a glint is a "hard" one. If dictionaries told the whole story, the question would not be on-topic here.

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways They aren't! But there is an interesting comparison. What makes a star twinkle? Is it the star itself... or atmospheric conditions? There are different adjectives to describe twinkling stars and blinking lights, so it seems reasonable that there are different words to describe the reflection of light from different surfaces. If poets have used artistic licence, that's fine, and I don't say in my answer that it is *wrong* to use it for either - I've focused on the dictionary definitions which *do* differ.

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways Plus, how dry is your hair? I think most people's hair has some moisture, or natural oils. It doesn't need to be super-greasy to glisten. Why do people use conditioner if not to add shine back to hair that has just been stripped of all natural oil? Conditioner puts some of that moisture back in. If you don't condition your hair it will be like kindling and I don't think anybody is going to write poetry about how your hair glistens.